# An analytical solution of time-dependent parabolic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I tried to write a code of ADI (alternating direction implicit) method in Matlab, but I do not know, how to find an analytical solution of my equation (which I need to know in my code). 
I have an equation which looks like:

$\frac{\partial U(t,x,y)}{\partial t} = A.\Delta U(t,x,y) + B(\frac{\partial U(t,x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial U(t,x,y)}{\partial x}) + f $

where $\Delta = \frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial y^2}$

$\qquad$ $A,B$ are constants

$\qquad$ $f$ is function dependent on $x,y,t$

and I know, how an initial conditon and Dirichlet condition looks like.
How could I find an analitical solution of the equation mentioned above? Which method should I use?

If it is needed, I can write how exactly my equation and conditions look like.

Thank you!

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you want an analytic solution or a numerical one? Why do you think that an analytical solution exists?

Comment: If you want to verify that your solver code is correct, look into MMS - method of manufactured solutions. Keep in mind that the error to the exact solution depends both on the space and time discretizations, if you refine only one of them, the other will be a constant contribution preventing error convergence to zero.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I need to write a code for 2D ADI method in Matlab. I found a code for 1D in book Computational Partial Differential Equations Using MATLAB - Jichun Li, Yi-Tung Chen. I tired to change it from 1D to 2D, but if I understand this code, I need to know analytical solution in this code .... I do not understand why, but I need it... I can write ADI method on the paper, but I got stuck in matlab code ....

Comment: @Ilovemath I still do not understand analytical solution of WHAT equation do you need? I have looked at ADI, it seems to be a method to solve special kind of linear systems. What you have a PDE, a differential equation. One can approximate a PDE by a linear system by discretizing it. Depending on what discretization procedure you use, you get a different type of linear system. Is your question on how to discretize the PDE? Or is it about analytical solution? If you want pure analytical solution, why do you need ADI?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I am so sorry. I do not know, how to explain it. I need to solve my PDE (dU/dt =....) and I need to use ADi method. But my teacher used an analytical solution in her code, so I thought that I have to use it too. I found "similar" code for 1D, but I do not know, how to change it (and I also do not know how to find an analytical solution). I posted my question also here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/how-to-write-a-code-of-2d-adi-method-in-matlab/35205#35205
I hope that there it is explained clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The [code you have found](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/how-to-write-a-code-of-2d-adi-method-in-matlab/35205#35205) solves a simple equation $\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}$ analytically by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). This allows the author to write the solution in the form of a sum, from which only a single term survives when they apply the boundary conditions. Also, the authors perform numerical solution of the PDE using the method called [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). Then they compare the analytical and numerical solutions.

For your case, separation of variables (in general) is not possible because of the free term $f(x,y,t)$. This term makes the equation inhomogeneous, and as far as I know, there is no general approach to solving inhomogeneous equations analytically.

That said, nothing is stopping you from solving your equation numerically. If you have been asked to solve this in a class, I believe you must have already covered finite differences or a similar discretization method

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that I cannot find an analytical solution. I think that I understand, but I got stuck with writing a code in Matlab. Could you write, please, how could I write a code for equations which I wrote? You do not have to write a whole code ... mabye I need only some hint.... I do not know, how to write it in Maltab...

Comment: @Ilovemath I will not do this. The purpose of this forum is to help people answer their questions, not do the work for them. Please, talk with your professor, ask him what exactly it is that you need to do, make sure that you understand the concept of finite differences and are able to code it for simple examples. I assure you that by that time you will be able to solve your problem yourself. If you still have a question after that, I'll be glad to help

Comment: If I had a helpful teacher, I would ask my teacher. But she wrote that she wont help us. Most of my classmates wrote to students who are oder then us, but I try to write it on my own ... I do not want to ask somebody to write a code ... I just ask for help ...